# How do I install a program to another HDD?

Tags: software-installation, hard-drive, ssd, games, steam

I've been trying to find a solution but couldn't so far and I feel very stupid. Just recently switched from windows, installed Ubuntu on my SSD. I want to install Steam and games to my 1TB HDD. But how do I do that? I'm having a really hard time to understand this.

Comment: The Steam client is installed alongside other software and you really can't change that. Steam games, however, you can install pretty much wherevr you want as long as your user as rwx permission on the given location. It's set in Steam settings > Downloads > Steam Library folders. Keep in mind that for most games an HDD is not recommend due to it being comparatively very slow.

Comment: Read the links in the suggested duplicate, the location changes -- most likely in your home dir's .steam directory these days.

Comment: You control the location of directories (which physical disks they are installed on), and packages generally install to specific directories (ie. your install setup dictates the drive you put the directory on); though some package formats give you more control than others. You've provided no OS & release details, nor package formats being used, so we can only give generic advice.

Answer (score 2):

In linux, you do not install a program on another partition ("drive"). Upon program installation, different components of the program are placed in dedicated functional system folders. That boils down to folders containing data of different applications. One can, however, distribute different system folders over different storage media. This is done in server systems. Also because system files rarely exceed 15 GB, they are typically kept on a single storage medium in personal computers.

Prefer installing software on the SSD. This makes a large difference in perceived system performance. Reserve your traditional HDD for storage of data, i.e. big static files or archive data.